# RadListView - force a re-layout

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

Using RadListView and I'm populating the list items during on onItemLoading event.

As one scrolls through a long list - list-items are discarded and re-generated automatically by the listview.

It seems to me that once re-generated - the list-item layout is not re-measured - as per the new contents of the onItemLoading() event.

e.g. A list-item Label has "A" and since the column width is "auto" - sized accordingly. When that object is reused again and now the Label is something longer - the column is still the width of the old content - so content gets truncated - actually blank gets displayed because the new contents don't fit.

I've verified this - took me all day.

How can I force a re-measure of the list-item during the onItemLoading event callback.

Comment: You could force the update of the RadListView via its `refresh` method, which will update the UI. - http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#refresh  However could you give me some more info about the problem or to add some example code, where I can see the problem. In regard to that do you use normal array or ObservableArray to load the items in your ListView?

Comment: The list-item layout is a grid-layout '<GridLayout columns="auto,*" rows="auto"><Label id="pi-date" row="0" col="0" /><Label text="Text" row="0" col="1" /></GridLayout>'. The within the itemLoading event callback, I dynamically update "pi-date" field with day of month - sometimes 1 digit and sometimes 2. It works all except when the list is long and when I scroll up and down. When the entry gets drawn - some entries which should be 2 digits are blank. If I look at the width of the column it looks like it was sized for the 1 digit day of month.

Comment: I'm using a ObservableArray. The listview works in every way. I would prefer just to re-measure the current listitem as opposed to calling refresh on the entire listview. It seems RadListView is doing the measure once when the object is created - not after each call to itemLoaded event.

Comment: Yes the easy fix is changing the GridLayout columns to ="32,*" or something similar..